# Force use of a constructor

Tags: rust

I want to give some business-rule guarantees about certain structs. For example, that an `EmailAddress` is a valid email, or that a `DateRange` has a from that lies before a from, and so on. So that when passing such a value around, it is guaranteed to adhere to all business rules for that struct.

```
struct InvalidEmailAddress;
struct EmailAddress {
  value: String
}

impl EmailAddress {
  fn new(value: String) -> Result<Self, InvalidEmailAddress> {
    if value.contains("@") { // I know, this isn't any sort of validation. It's an example.
        Ok(Self { value })
    } else {
        Err(InvalidEmailAddress)
    }
  }
}
```

Ignoring that now `new()` behaves unexpected (it probably would be better to use a `build()` method), this brings an issue: **When someone builds an `EmailAddress` through the constructor, it is guaranteed to be "valid". But when someone constructs it as normal struct, it may not be.**:

```
let guaranteed_valid = EmailAddress::new(String::from("hi@example.com")).unwrap();
let will_crash = EmailAddress::new(String::from("localhost")).unwrap()
let unknown_valid = EmailAddress { value: String::from("hi-at-example.com") }
```

I would like to prohibit any users of those structs from constructing them directly like in the last line.

Is that possible at all? Are there any more ways someone could construct an EmailAddress in an invalid way?

I'm OK with placing the structs in a module, and using public/private visibility if that is possible at all. But from what I can see, any code that wants to now enforce the `EmailAddress` type, say a `send_report(to: EmailAddress)` would have access to the struct and can build it directly. Or am I missing something crucial?

Comment: You can't directly see/modify a field unless it's accessible, usually with `pub`

Comment: What do you mean with "users of those structs"? If you mean "users of your crate", you already solved it, they can't. If your struct is in its own file, you already solved the issue as well, as it's in its own mod and can't be created. Also, read [the chapter about visibility in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html) to understand the reasons behind this.

Comment: A "user of the struct" is any developer who creates the struct and then passes it around. Not necessarily via a crate. But as your link (thanks!) and the answer below points out, we can achieve this "limitation for users" by placing the structs in a mod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place your struct in a module. That way any code outside of that module will only be able to access the public functionality. Since `value` is not public, direct construction will not be allowed:

```
mod email {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct InvalidEmailAddress;
    pub struct EmailAddress {
        value: String,
    }

    impl EmailAddress {
        pub fn new(value: String) -> Result<Self, InvalidEmailAddress> {
            if value.contains("@") {
                // I know, this isn't any sort of validation. It's an example.
                Ok(Self { value })
            } else {
                Err(InvalidEmailAddress)
            }
        }
    }
}

use email::EmailAddress;

fn main() {
    let e = EmailAddress::new("foo@bar".to_string()).unwrap(); // no error
    //let e = EmailAddress { value: "invalid".to_string() };   // "field `value` of struct `EmailAddress` is private"
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a2d88e1e05f65d39d8fc408a181e944)

More details on visibility in [the Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the [relevant chapter in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html) for more information.